# Web Reference Help: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Ok, so I'm learning about ASP.NET by making a simple program to read in a user's gmail credentials and construct an email from their input into the Console, but I'm getting a new error that I was not get yesterday, and I have not changed ANY code. The error is on line 41, so I have provided that (the rest of the code is just reading input into Strings) I have disabled my firewall to no avail, and have also tried "http://localhost/Service.asmx", which doesn't work either. I've also tried restarting IIS.

I'm completely new to this subject, but the error suggests, to me, that the program is communicating with the server but is being denied by a blocked port, but I have disabled my firewall and the error persists. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
/*40*/  Communication_Service.Service CommServiceProxy = new Communication_Service.Service();
/*41*/  Result = CommServiceProxy.SendMail(GmailAccount, Password, To, Subject, Body);
```

***There was an error dowloading http://localhost:4932/Service.asmx. Unable to connect to the remove server. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:4492***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are running cassini (development server).  The application at http://localhost:4932/ needs to be started.  You probably have multiple sites and need multiple start up projects.  Right click your solution and click set start up project, pick multiple, and select all your websites.  On VS goto debug, run without debugging and they should all start.